# PHP MySQL date ordering

Tags: php, mysql

Ok im trying to order results by date and time in an ascending order but so far this isnt working :(

```
$kalendarquery = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT
people.firstname,
people.lastname,
people.id,
people.avatar,
dates.date,
dates.time,
dates.timezonedate
FROM people
INNER JOIN dates ON
people.id=dates.invited_id
WHERE dates.inviter_id='$user_id' AND status='1'
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(dates.date,' ',dates.time), '%d/%m/%y %h:%m')     ASC
LIMIT 50");
```

I mean it doesnt order it by the lowest date to the biggest

Comment: what order are you seeing in the query result?

Comment: What is dates.date? A string field from the looks of it, but what's in there? Also "it doesn't order it" is insufficient information. What output do you get based on what data? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Why not just `ORDER BY dates.date ASC, dates.time ASC`? In my opinion it's easier to always use Unix timestamps to store date-times in the database. You should think about the format when you view the results to the user, not when you store and sort it, there's no meaning in slashes and colons for the database.

Comment: Im getting the highest date whatever i put (ASC or DESC) i get first 27.03.2015 then 19.07.2015 but it doesnt change if i put asc or desc and i have 2015-03-27 in that field

Answer (score 0):

Your second parameter to `STR_TO_DATE` has to match the date format in your char field; otherwise, the conversion will just return `NULL` for every row which is why its not being ordered.

So since your dates are formatted like `27.03.2015` using `.` as delimeter, you need to make sure you use `.` in that parameter rather than `/`.

Also lower case `%y` is for 2-digit year, so you need `%Y` because you're using 4-digits:

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(dates.date,' ',dates.time), '%d.%m.%Y %h:%i')     ASC
```

You didn't give an example of your time format, but you can figure out how to do it properly by reading the [docs for date_format()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). But notice above I changed `%m` to `%i` in the time part: you were using `%m` for both month and minutes which is obviously wrong.